# How long would it take a Victorian to travel from central Germany to the UK?

Tags: europe, transportation, travel, imperial-germany, victorian

Specifically from Lauscha in 1862, does anyone know how extensive railways were then?

Comment: Are you looking for an exact timing or just a rough range?

Comment: Pretty close to this question:[the-speed-of-sea-travel-in-the-beginning-of-19th-century](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/36348/the-speed-of-sea-travel-in-the-beginning-of-19th-century)

Comment: The railway line from Probstzella wasn't extended to Lauscha, and Sonneberg until the early 20th century when [Lichte station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichte_(Thuringia)_east_station) became an express railway station.

Comment: More generally, you can read more about the [History of German railways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rail_transport_in_Germany) on Wikipedia, which would give you the basic information you'd need to work out an estimate.

Answer (score 11):

(The maps are from an [Atlas Obscura article](http://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/isochrone-maps-color-time) on Isochronic maps and the [wikipedia entry on German Railways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rail_transport_in_Germany).)

Here's an isochronic map centered on London from the early 1880s to give a feel of how long it would take ~20 years later:

[image: Travel time from London in 1880]

The German rail network in 1861 suggests there already was a track nearby (you can see a track between Eisenach and Bamberg if you zoom in) so the travel time would likely have been within 10 days in 1862 as well:

[image: German rail network in 1861]

For completeness, the travel times in 1914 to illustrate how fast things evolved back then:

[image: Travel time from London in 1914]

Comment: I sure hope this answers the question, because I'm upvoting for the maps regardless.